# Build a jagged array from a String in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, matrix

I have to code this "create a matrix from a `String`:

```
 * The string if formatted as follow:
 *  - Each row of the matrix is separated by a newline
 *    character \n
 *  - Each element of the rows are separated by a space
 *  For example, the String "0 1\n2 3" represent the
 *  matrix:
      [0 1]
      [2 3]
```

In the exercise the matrix can be a "Jagged Array" and here is my code :

```
int[][] tab = null 
int compteur = 0
int position = 0
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char l = s.charAt(i);
    String p = String.valueOf(l);
    if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
        tab[compteur][position] = s.charAt(i);
        position++;
    else if(p.equals("/n")) {
        position = 0;
        compteur ++;
    }
}
return tab
```

Comment: arrays are of fixed size in java. you could incrementally create bigger arrays, determine the dimensions in a first pass before populating or use lists instead. pls don't link to png, but post the code as text.

Comment: You've used quotes around the phrase asking for a matrix.  Are we assuming that the matrix is truly rectangular (same number of columns in each row)...or could it be a true "jagged array"?  That would be an array of arrays where the number of elements in each row could be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code :

```
public static int[][] method(String s) {
    String[] x = s.split("\n");
    int[][] out = new int[x.length][x[0].split(" ").length];
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        String[] y = x[i].split(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
            out[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(y[j]);
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

IN :

```
String s = "0 1\n2 3\n4 5"
```

OUT :

```
int[][] array = [0 1],[2 3],[4 5]
```

This above code works fine for square matrix, but here the code that works for any kind of matrix ! :

```
    public static int[][] method(String s) {
    String[] x = s.split("\n");
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (String string : x) {
        int l = string.split(" ").length;
        max = l > max ? l : max;
    }
    int[][] out = new int[x.length][max];
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        String[] y = x[i].split(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
            out[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(y[j]);
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

IN :

```
String s = "0 1\n2 3\n4 5 6\n1"
```

OUT :

```
int[][] array = [0 1 0],[2 3 0],[4 5 6],[1 0 0]
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but Lionel I read your answer and maybe I don't understand one point or maybe your code doesn't work for every String. I mean when you said " int[][] out = new int[x.length][x[0].split(" ").length]" it work only for square matrix ? What if my string is "1 2\n 6 3 9" ?

Comment: You're right, and I added a "not square matrix" part in my original post !

Answer (score 1):

@Lionel Ding's solution will work, of course, but it's worth mentioning that using streams could arguably be more elegant. The logic would remain the same, however - you split the string by the `\n` character, and then split every line by the ' ' character, parse the individual strings to `int`s and collect the result to an `int[][]`:

```
private static int[][] toMatrix(String s) {
    return Arrays.stream(s.split("\n"))
                 .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(" "))
                                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray())
                 .toArray(int[][]::new);
}
```

Comment: Hello Lionel and Mureinik and thank you for your answer. I have one question for both of you : Lionel I read your answer and maybe I don't understand one point or maybe your code doesn't work for every String. I mean when you said " int[][] out = new int[x.length][x[0].split(" ").length]" it work only for square matrix ? What if my string is "1 2\n 6 3 9" ? For Mureinik : I don't understand the streams, do you have a video or API that introduce this ? I'm a beginner thank you !!!